# X-axis of sliding/window correlation

Tags: r, correlation, sliding-window

I am trying to perform sliding correlation with window=11years.
Here's my code:

```
library(gtools)
var1<-rnorm(52,0.010,0.05)
var2<-rnorm(52,0.015,0.01)
dat<-merge(var1,var2)
dat$year<-seq(1961,2012,1)

rc<-running(dat$x,dat$y,fun=cor, width=11)
```

I want to plot the output as a simple line plot like this:

```
plot(rc,type="l")
```

My problem is the x-axis. How do I match the correlation value with the years? Something like adding a filler value "0"?

Any suggestions on how I can do this correctly in R.

I'll appreciate any help.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rc <- running(var1, var2, fun = cor, width = 11)
plot(1971:2012, rc, type="l")
```